# How to drag and flick a node in SpriteKit while gravity is present?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsworld

With my current code, the node is extremely laggy, and moves or teleports in random directions for some reason when its flicked. How can i fix this, and also can someone explain why it is teleporting and moving to random places in the scene.

Also, is there anyway to allow the node to be moved only when it is dragged from its position, rather than being at the gesturerecognizer's coordinates at all times?

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pan(_:)))
    

    view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    circleNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    self.addChild(circleNode)
}


@objc func pan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
   

    
    if recognizer.state == .changed {

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        var location = recognizer.location(in: self.view!)
        location = self.convertPoint(fromView: location)
        
        
        circleNode.position = location
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.8)
        let transformerX = 1024/self.view!.frame.size.width
        let transformerY = 768/self.view!.frame.size.height
        let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)
        circleNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: velocity.x * transformerX, dy: velocity.y * transformerY))



    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Here is some code I was playing around with. I'm able to drag and flick a spear (spear Image) and also "pop" a pig head. This is the whole GameScene.Remove the code you don't need. :)

```
 import SpriteKit
 import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate  {

  enum CollisionTypes: UInt32{
    case spear = 1
    case wall = 2
    case head = 4
  }


  var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
  var touching: Bool = false

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    //Add contact delegate
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    
    self.addChild(spearNode)
    self.addChild(headNode)
}



lazy var spearNode: SKSpriteNode = {
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spear2")
    node.name = "Spear"
    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: node.texture!,
                                     size: CGSize(width: node.frame.width  , height: node.frame.height))
    node.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX , y:self.frame.midY)
    node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    node.size = CGSize(width: node.frame.width , height: node.frame.height )
    node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.spear.rawValue
    node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.head.rawValue
    node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.head.rawValue
    return node
}()

lazy var headNode: SKSpriteNode = {
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Pig")
    node.name = "Pig"
    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: node.texture!,
                                     size: CGSize(width: node.frame.width  , height: node.frame.height))
    node.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX , y:self.frame.maxY - 100)
    node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    node.size = CGSize(width: node.frame.width / 2  , height: node.frame.height / 2 )
    node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.head.rawValue
    return node
    
}()

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact){
    guard let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node else {return}
    guard let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node else {return}
    
    print("Contacted")
    
    if nodeA.name == "Pig" && nodeB.name == "Spear"{
        nodeA.removeFromParent() 
    }
    
    if nodeA.name == "Spear" && nodeB.name == "Pig"{    
        nodeB.removeFromParent()
    }
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in:self)
    
    if spearNode.frame.contains(location) {
        touchPoint = location
        touching = true
    }
}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    touchPoint = location
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touching = false
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx:0, dy: -9.8)
    
    if touching {
        let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/60.0
        let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-spearNode.position.x, dy: touchPoint.y-spearNode.position.y)
        let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
        spearNode.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try it out in the morning

Comment: I can't get it to work at all. It crashes when any of the objects are tapped because spearNode.physicsBody is nil when unwrapped, so I gave it an explicit body size and it moves now but it just moves randomly and does not follow the gestures. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Just assign an image to the SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yourImage")

Comment: I assigned an image and it makes no difference

Comment: So what did you actually change in the code? Code works perfectly on my side.

Comment: Can you link a recording or screenshot of how it’s supposed to function. I changed spearNode.physicsBody to SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: node.frame.width, height: node.frame.height)) because the app kept on crashing due to physicsBody being nil.

Comment: I don’t know what I’m doing wrong. I guess maybe a rectangle image doesn’t work in this case, but I it still shouldn’t be moving wierdly

Comment: let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spear.png")

Comment: Ive added the spear to an edit of my post. :) Use it to see if your image is the issue.

Comment: Save the image file as spear@2x.png and use SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spear") to add it to the node

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. I dont know why my spear did not work with it.

Comment: Could be a few things.Was your previous image transparent? Could also be a size issue. Anyways. Glad we found the problem. Started worrying. haha

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply impart a force to the object based upon the swipe gesture rather than turning off gravity, manually moving the object, and then turning on gravity again when the swipe is over?

Comment: If gravity is just set in the beginning (y: -9.8) the ball can’t be dragged because it falls at every position and doesn’t stay at the coordinates of the recognizer